# Developer Tools at Chrome or Firefox: how can I see help (suggestions) from libraries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, firebug

I need this:

[image: firefox chrome developers tools dark theme suggestions at console]

...for external js-libraries. For example - I have extension for Firebug ([Firequery](http://firequery.binaryage.com/)) for handling Jquery:

[image: Firequery]

This planet have extension for suggestions for any js-library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Libraries included in your site's code will automatically be available within the command line of the devtools.

Example:

1. Go to http://jquery.com/
2. Open the devtool
3. Switch to its command line
4. Execute `window.$('div')` within the command line

=> You'll get an array of `<div>`s.

*Note that they are not added to the `document` object but the `window` object. So e.g. jQuery will be available via `window.jQuery` or `window.$`.*

Also all major devtools provide some command line API including the dollar sign function for selecting elements. See e.g. the [description of the Command Line API](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line_API) in Firebug. So for that you don't need an extension like FireQuery.

Furthermore these command line APIs obscure library functions like the `$()` function from jQuery. I.e. when you type `$` you'll actually access the command line API, not the jQuery `$()` function. To access the jQuery function you have to prepend it by `window` as stated above.